# How can I call a function in radare2 debug session?

Tags: radare2

In `gdb` I can easily do the following:

```
(gdb) call function(arg)
```

what is the equivalent in `r2`?

There is no `call` function in debug session so this doesn't work:

```
[0x08048795] call sym.func
```

Inject opcode also didn't work as I tried this:

```
[0x08048795] dx call syn.func
```

Answer (score 2):

radare2 is not a source code debugger so you might see some things that are missing in comparison to what you got in GDB.

This feature is not implemented in radare2 and I'm not sure will be. Anyway, you can point `eip` to the function you want to execute by using `dr eip=0x...` but you'll have a hard time with passing arguments through the stack (although it is possible).

You can also [check](http://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options/d/dx/) `dx?` to see examples of how `dx` should be executed. Check `gs` as well to execute syscalls.

Also, you can use radare2 with gdbserver/gdb so you better [check this out](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/debugger/remote_gdb.html) as well.

[Here is](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/debugger/migration.html) a good place to read about migrating from GDB to radare2.